# Install on single or different server sql, tfs and AD

Tags: tfs, sql-server-2012

I have some question.

I need install tfs 2012, SQL Server 2012 with auth on Active Directory (AD).

What is better:

- install all on single server, or take two server: first SQL Server, and tfs, second- AD?
- If I install SQL Server, is it better use AD account or default (NT Service\SQLServerAgent, NT Service\SQLServerEngine...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1: I would go with installing all 3 on separate servers but if you don't have an option you can install TFS and SQL Server on one box and AD on separate. Think what will happen if TFS brings down the server your AD and SQL Server will be down too if you have all of them on a single server. Now it its not a Production environment installing them on one server should be fine.

Answer 2: I would suggest to use AD account.